# Isomorphism between $H^1(\mathbb{Z}_p, M)$ and $M_{\mathbb{Z}_p}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, group-cohomology

Let $\Gamma$ be a multiplicative group isomorphic to the $p$-adic integers $(\mathbb{Z}_p,+)$, and let $M$ be a discrete torsion $\Gamma$-module. Let $\gamma$ be a topological generator for $\Gamma$. Since $\Gamma$ is a topologically free group, we know that the cohomogical dimension of $\Gamma$ is $1$, hence $H^n(\Gamma, M)=0$ for every $n\ge2$. It also seems true that
$$ M_\Gamma:=M/(\gamma-1)M\cong H^1(\Gamma,M), $$
but I can't find a proof of this, and I'm not sure that the conditions for $M$ are enough. The only hypothesis I may add is that $M^\Gamma$ is finite.

The most naural way to find an isomorphism seems to involve the morphism
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&H^1(\Gamma,M)\longrightarrow M/(\gamma-1)M\\
&[\xi]\longmapsto [\xi(\gamma)]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $[\cdot]$ denotes the class inside the quotient. This map is easily seen to be injective, but I can't prove the surjectivity.

Comment: What about for each $m \in M$ defining a crossed homomorphism $\xi_m$ via $\xi_m: \gamma \mapsto m$? The property of being a crossed homomorphism should tell us what this is on each $\gamma^n$, and via $M$ being $\Gamma$-torsion this should well-define $\xi_m$ on all of $\Gamma$. Checking that everything is well-defined, the class of this $\xi_m$ should be a preimage of $[m]$. I have not checked the details though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution in the book of Neukirch, Schmidt, Wingberg "Cohomology of Number Fields", Proposition 1.7.7. It says:

Let $G=\prod_{p\in S}\mathbb{Z}_p$ be a torsion-free procyclic group and let $A$ be a discrete $G$-module. If $A$ is $S$-torsion, then $H^1(G,A)\cong A_G$.

The proof involves a result in the cohomology of cyclic groups that is proved using cup products, but infact the map that gives the isomorphism is the one I mentioned.

Comment: And is its inverse the one I sketched in the comment?

Comment: They don't construct explicitely an inverse, but I think that if the map I mentioned is an isomorphism, your map must be the inverse.